# What does ** mean in C language?

Tags: c, pointers

could anyone explain me please what does this piece of code mean?

```
  int **d= (int**)malloc((m+1)*sizeof(int));
```

What are those ** for the d and the (int) ? Are they someway related to pointers?

Comment: Yes, they are related to pointers. This is not the way to learn C. Please obtain a textbook.

Comment: Don't confuse with the * before `sizeof`.. It has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sizeof(int *)` or, better yet, `sizeof(*d)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int** d; //pointer to a pointer to an integer
```

Comment: And what about (int**) before the malloc call?

Comment: the malloc call returns the pointer to the allocated address.. to cast it into a pointer to pointer to integer, that call is used. that is type casting.

Comment: Note that in C the cast is both redundant and potentially dangerous. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @paul. ook, got what you saying. didnt know this.  :)